# Null Pointer Exception on startService

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am trying to start a service from within itself so it will not be stopped on unbind. When I use the .class method it does not work. When I use the full name it works fine. This also seems to be the case if I do the call from an activity. I can not figure out what is going on!

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
super.onCreate();

// Null Pointer Exception
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);

// Null Pointer Exception
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);

// Works!
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.mypackage.MyService");
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Some of the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mypackage"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="MyApplication">

    <service android:name="MyService" android:enabled="true"></service>
```

Also, the exact error is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.mypackage @427d2b80 with Intent { cmp=com.mypackage/.MyService }: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It looks like the first two may simply not be supported: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)

Comment: Show us your AndroidManifest.xml (the relevant part regarding the service)

Comment: I added the exact error because it looks like there is an extra dot in there and I cannot figure out where it is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you need to put the full class in the manifest, or at least start it with "." (from the docs). I was using Eclipse to set up the manifest and it didn't seem to have a problem figuring out which class it was so I didn't see the problem. I also never had the issue before. It also turns out that

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.mypackage.MyService");
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Actually does nothing. The required line in the manifest is:

```
<service android:name="com.mypackage.MyService">
```

And then use:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);
```